# Set with an index that is uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Can we define a set such that:
$$S = \bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{x\} ~ ~ ?$$

The only thing that bothers me about this set is that the index is uncountably infinite. Could one also say that:
$$S = \mathbb{R}?$$

Comment: Yes, in this case $S=\mathbb{R}$. Unions and intersections can be done over any index set, even if it's higher cardinality than the reals.

Comment: Formally, you need an index set that is *well-ordered*, but there exist well-ordered sets of the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ and hence such a set could be used to give a well-order for $\mathbb{R}$ that would suffice (better to just use that well-ordered set of same cardinality unless you have a specific reason to use $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JustinBenfield No you don't. Why would the index set need to be well-ordered?

Comment: I suppose you *can* define a union without any order on the index set by universal quantification, but you need to be careful what you do with an indexed collection where the index isn't well-ordered. For instance (transfinite) induction is off the table without a well-order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $S=\Bbb R$ in your example. There's nothing wrong with taking a union of uncountably many sets, but sometimes we can say more about the result when the union is countable. In particular, [measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) are by definition only countably additive - otherwise we'd get contradictions like $1=\mu([0,1])=\mu(\bigcup_{x\in[0,1]}\{x\})=\sum_{x\in\Bbb [0,1]}\mu(\{x\})=0$. Maybe your discomfort with uncountable unions stems from an intuition about measure additivity.